# Least Square with quadratic constraint

Tags: statistics, optimization, quadratics, least-squares

We need to solve the following  least square problem 
\begin{align}
    Y=X\theta+W,
\end{align}
with quadratic constraint
\begin{align}
 \theta^TA\theta = 0,
\end{align}
where  the complex matrix $X \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, the complex vector $Y \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times 1}$, and the real matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$  are given, and $W \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times1}$ is the complex additive white Gaussian noise (zero mean and unit variance). $\theta$ is the parameter to estimate, so basically we need to solve

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rrclcl}
\displaystyle \min_{\theta} & {\|Y-X\theta\|^2} \\
\textrm{s.t.} &\theta^TA\theta& = & 0 \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
in a closed form.

Indeed we try to have some intuition by starting from working on a special case: $m=n=4$, $A =\begin{pmatrix}0_{2\times2}&  a \\ 0_{2\times 2} & 0_{2\times 2}\end{pmatrix}$, where $a = \begin{pmatrix}0&  1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.  By employing Lagrange multipliers we have
\begin{align}
    -2X^HY+2X^HX\theta+\lambda \begin{pmatrix}0_{2\times2}&  a \\ -a & 0_{2\times 2}\end{pmatrix}\theta &= 0\nonumber \\
     \theta^T\begin{pmatrix}0_{2\times2}&  a \\ 0_{2\times 2} & 0_{2\times 2}\end{pmatrix}\theta &= 0
\end{align}

Did we do something wrong? Can anyone help us? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You "need" to solve it in closed form? Are you assuming a closed form solution exists? That hardly seems an obvious proposition. Would you settle for a numerical solution?

Comment: seems to be an off-the-shelf problem.